# Recovering data from failing external hard disk drive

Tags: windows, hard-drive, data-recovery

Last week my friend backed up all of his stuff (literally all of his personal and business documents), about 400GB worth of data to an external 500GB hard disk drive.

That same day, when trying to restore the data to another hard disk drive, at first the drive was not accessible. He reformatted the internal hard drive drive, reinstalled Windows and wanted to restore his documents to the internal drive. So the external hard disk drive is the only one currently containing his documents

But after trying on a few different PCs and USB ports, Windows suggested running CHKDSK to repair drive errors. 
After about 30 hours running, CHKDSK reported that a large number of files/bad sectors had been repaired/reallocated but threw an error message, claiming that the hdd didn't have enough space to restore the recovered files.

So now the drive can be accessed, albeit very slowly. But the largest folder (which contained about 200GB) has disappeared. However, the space is still being occupied by files, as the reported free space is about 100GB (the same as before this happened), but only about 150-200GB are in visible folders. There are 3 hidden folders on the root of the drive: `Found.000`, `Found.001`, `Found.002`, each of them containing exactly 10,000 files, of the form `filexxxx.chk`, where `xxxx` is a 4 digit number.

We've tried using data recovery tools (eg Easeus), but they only look for deleted files. Also, we tried CHK-Back and it manages to recover about 50% of the files, but with generic names and without recovering the original folder structure.

The hard disk drive file system is FAT32.

The drive's SMART status reports 5 realocated bad sectors. I'm assuming that the errors may have come from disconnecting the hdd from the PC while writing.

So here are my questions:

1. Although we haven't written or deleted anything from the drive since this happened, would it be a good idea to delete the folders which are not important, to create enough free space for CHKDSK to restore the recovered files?
2. If enough space can be cleared, will CHKDSK recover the files with file names, folder structure, etc, or will it do the same thing as CHK-Back?
3. Would it be a good idea to clone the hard disk drive to another drive and work on that drive, to avoid further messing up the corrupted  hard disk drive?
4. Is it possible to recover the drive's original FAT, or has CHKDSK destroyed it in the file recovery process?
5. Other ideas? Recommended software?

Comment: Get spinRite grc.com

Comment: What I am having a hard time understanding is which drive is dead and what about the backup mentioned at the beginning? I mean I read this, “Last week my friend backed up all of his stuff (literally all of his personal and business documents), about 400GB worth of data to an external 500GB hard disk drive.” and to me it seems like the 500GB drive has a backup? Or is that what’s failing?

Comment: If the data is very valuable monetarily (or even for sentimental reasons) you can take the drive to professional data recovery service. Some of them even give free estimates and tell you if the data looks to be recoverable or not. You need to know beforehand though - it will be very expensive!

Comment: @SunnyskyguyEE75 - Spinrite is worthless when it comes to USB devices. It has zero support for them.  Spinrite in general is worthless due to the fact it has not been updated and there are numerous problems that justify it being updated.

Comment: @KidACrimson - I agree professional data recovery is the best course of action.

Comment: @Ramhound Spinrite can be mounted to a USB drive to test the installed HDD.  If  Windows is working , ( free) Recuva using “defunct volume” option to look for files from a corrupt FAT32  is possible. it may be able to recover too if not over-written.  It depends on the actions taken so far. But you or anyone are entitled to your opinion of worthlessness.

Comment: @JakeGould - he backed up his documents from his Windows/internal drive to the external 500GB hdd (the one failing). Then he formated the internal drive, reinstalled windows and wanted to restore his documents to the internal drive. So the external hdd is the only one containing his documents.

Comment: Whatever your friend does, right now he needs to stop using the drive until he decides on a solution. Continued use or attempts to access the data without proper care could potentially damage further data.